# Where is the Earthgift Shrine in Final Fantasy?

Tags: ios, final-fantasy

I am currently playing the original Final Fantasy for the iPhone and can not remember where the Earthgift Shrine is on the over world map.

I have just beaten Lich and looking to return because the statue disappeared once I beat him.

Comment: I think you mean "Earth Shrine"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's between Castle Cornelia (beginning of game) and Chaos Shrine (to the northwest).